# How can I remove all my duplicate uploads on YouTube at once?

Tags: youtube

I have hundreds of "Rejected (duplicate upload)":

[image]

How can I remove all my duplicate uploads on YouTube at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube does not allow to remove all duplicate uploads at once.